# Como limitar o tempo de uma consulta ao Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

Gostaria de saber um modo de limitar o tempo das requisições ao firebase ou mesmo poder cancelar a consulta em andamento caso haja demora na resposta do banco.

Comment: As consultas no Firebase são efetuadas de forma assíncrona. Infelizmente ele ainda não oferece uma forma de fazer isso. E duvido que seja possível implementar tal coisa, por causa da assíncronia.

Comment: Você pode definir um valor inicial para uma variável, quando a requisição ao firebase finalizar, então essa variável será atualizada